# How to add Environment Variables in Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, environment-variables

I am working on a python project using **Visual Studio Code** on **Ubuntu OS** and I need to set environment variables without using the integrated terminal, I want to be able to set it using a file or an efficient medium asides my terminal.

Please help

Comment: Your `/etc/environment` should store environment variables so you simply need to edit it from console.

Comment: Please how do I do this...can you explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to find a solution that enabled me specify my variables in a **.env file** in Visual Studio Code

I used a python module called **python-dotenv** the setup for installing it can be found in https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/

So follow these steps:

1. In your Visual Studio Code integrated terminal, install python-dotenv using `pip install python-dotenv`
2. In your python code add this at the top of the code

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
```

3. In your code folder i.e where the python code specified above lies, create a file called **.env**
4. Now specify all your environment variables inside the .env file e.g

```
DB_PORT=1212
DB_NAME=test_db
DB_USER=test_user
```

5. Now run the python code and watch the environment variable work in action

Comment: This has nothing to do with Visual Studio Code, it works independently

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/environment` is the second boot file when logging into the Linux system.

You can use the following command to open, or open the file in the directory:

```
~$ sudo gedit /etc/environment
```

Environment variables are defined here. We can add environment variables you need, such as:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/yan/anaconda2/bin"
```

So we add anaconda2 to PATH environment variable.